# ¿Como recuperar parte datos compuestos con JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Tengo una pequeña aplicación que conecta con `postgresql`, esta almacena 2 objetos,

- Equipo que tiene tres valores : tienda de tipo `String`, gama de tipo `String` y finalmente precio del tipo `int`.

Para almacenarlos, ocupo un tipo compuesto por los tres valores que he llamado `datosPC`.

- `Componentes` que lo guardo con un `array` de 3 datos tipo `string` en la base de datos.

**Mi pregunta: Al hacer el resultSet, ¿cómo puedo recuperar uno de los valores de Equipo? ¿Y para recuperar un valor de Componentes?**

Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Haz una visita por el recorrido y por Meta para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Deberías añadir algo mas de código para que tu pregunta sea más clara y específica. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnfoo = 
500");
while (rs.next())
{
System.out.print("Column 1 returned ");
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```